# upstart script to start a task after hardware clock has been started

Tags: clock, upstart, ntp

I have a process that tries to make an SSL connection after start up, but that fails if the clock has not yet been set (the dates don't match the effective dates on the certificates).  Is it possible to configure upstart to only start the process after the internal clock is set?

The default setting for the clock is 2010-01-01, so perhaps something like `date >= 2014` is sufficient (obviously not legit upstart syntax, but the concept holds).

The best I could figure out was to start up after NTP has started, but that doesn't necessarily mean the clock has been set as the network connection establishment may be delayed or not available for a while.

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution is probably to just poll the date and wait 500ms or whatever before trying again if the date isn't sane yet.

Comment: how do you do something like that in upstart?  my skills upstart are...  non-existent.  I suspect using a `task`?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I ended up doing:

```
start on started connman
stop on runlevel [016]

script
        YEAR=$(date +'%Y')
        until [ $YEAR -ge "2014" ]; do
                sleep 5
                YEAR=$(date +'%Y')
        done
        python access_point.py
end script
```

I wait until the connection manager is running and then I check the year every 5 seconds until the year is 2014 or greater.